# Azure: How can I add Tags to managed Ressource Groups and ressources created by Synapse Analytics, Databricks, AKS or Purview?

Tags: azure, azure-policy, azure-resource-group

I would like to ask how I'm able to add tags to managed resource groups and managed resources. With deployment of for example, Synapse or AKS, managed resource groups and resources are automatically created.

Unfortunately, I'm not able to add tags directly. I get a error message with a deny. I have tried using policies remediation tasks but some time it works and some time it doesn't. I'm not sure why this is the case. Is there a way to deploy tags to managed ressource groups?

best regards

Comment: At least for AKS all the tags that I put on the AKS resource itself, I see those are replicated to the managed resource group and the resources within

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed. I didn't know it's being replicated...